# Communicating between controllers without events

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering what would be the best way communicating between controllers without events.(It looks like $emit and $broadcast all involved with events.)

I have this line of code and if hospitalList length != 0, I want to assign true  in other controller's variable.

```
 $scope.hospitalList = Hospital.query();
```

thanks,

Comment: may I inquire why you would not want to use Pub\Sub (events) ? Event driven programming is in general a good architecture design, unless you have some edge case.

Comment: You could have a service maintain the value outside of either controller, and your markup could be data-bound to a function that queries that service...

Comment: I realized that  the above line returns an empty array immediately and adds the result from the request later when the response arrives. It should be like                     $scope.hospitalList = Hospital.query(function(){ ... }

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Global variables

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

$rootScope is the parent scope for all the scopes. So any values that we expose here will be available to all child scopes.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to share data or communication between controllers
1.Events that we do not want
2.services/factories: we can store data in service and that can be available in other controllers but if two different controllers are on same page like header and some view. we can not change it immidiately again we have to fire an event
3.$rootscope but you should not save thing in some object which never gets destroyed